# Apps script code for moving rows through a drop-down menu not working

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm new to apps scripts and coding in general. I'm trying to code a spread sheet so that when a specific word is chosen from a drop-down menu, the row would move to a specific sheet. The drop-down menu has 2 options and both must have different result when chosen. When "Alpha" is selected the row must disappear from the original sheet and then move to the "alpha" sheet. When "Beta" is chosen, the row must not disappear from the original sheet but still move to the "Beta" spreadsheet. I'm very inexperienced with coding so I would love if someone could review my code and point out errors.

Here is my code:

```
function onEdit(e) {
 const src = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  const r = e.range;
  if (r.columnStart != 8 || r.rowStart == 1 || e.value != "ALPHA");{
   const dest1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("ALPHA");
   src.getRange(r.rowStart,1,1,13).moveTo(dest1.getRange(dest1.getLastRow()+1,1,1,13));
   src.deleteRow(r.rowStart);
  }
  if (r.columnStart != 8 || r.rowStart == 1 || e.value != "BETA");{
   const dest2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("BETA");
   src.getRange(r.rowStart,1,1,13).moveTo(dest2.getRange(dest2.getLastRow()+1,1,1,13));
  }
  }
```

The code works if it is a single if statement, but when I add the second if statement it breaks down completely. For example, when I select "BETA" in the drop down menu, it moves that row and the row bellow it, one to the "ALPHA" sheet and one to the "BETA" sheet.

Comment: Are you sure that you want the semicolon here: `(r.columnStart != 8 || r.rowStart == 1 || e.value != "ALPHA");`

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know what the sheet looks like but I'm guessing something like this might work.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (e.range.columnStart == 8 && e.range.rowStart > 1 && e.value) {
    const dest1 = e.source.getSheetByName(e.value);//get sheetname from e.value
    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1, 1, 13).moveTo(dest1.getRange(dest1.getLastRow() + 1, 1, 1, 13));
    sh.deleteRow(e.range.rowStart);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That code works beautifully. Yeah pretty much column 8 is the one with the drop-down menu, and I want the first 13 columns moved for each row that is edited. Now, any ideas on how to make it so that the row is moved when "alpha" is chosen, and copied (original row does not go away) when "beta" is chosen?

Comment: Is alpha or beta the exact name of a sheet? Have you looked for errors in the execution logs.